# Opentelemetry JVM Metrics

Tags: monitoring, metrics, open-telemetry, elastic-apm, observability

I'm monitoring Java apps with Opentelemetry and exported data to Elastic APM. This integration works well, however we are missing some critical information about metrics.

We want to collect information about the host system and jvm metrics.

Openetelemetry collector is running as sidecar in k8s and its conf is below:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: app-sidecar
spec:
  mode: sidecar
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          http:
          grpc:
    exporters:
      logging:
      otlp:
        endpoint: http://endpoint:8200
        headers: 
          Authorization: Bearer token
        tls:
          insecure: true
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          exporters: [logging, otlp]
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          exporters: [logging, otlp]
        logs: 
          receivers: [otlp]
          exporters: [logging, otlp]
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your Java app with java agent [opentelemetry-javaagent.jar](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) (OTEL java autoinstrumentation). Configure it to export metrics (it provides by default JVM metrics), for example `OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp, OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=<your side car otel collector otlp grpc endpoint>"` - check doc for right doc/syntax.

Comment: Jan Garaj:  no luck , please find jvm params when server starts ```+ exec java -XX:MinRAMPercentage=70 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70 --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/app/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar -Dotel.service.name=workspace-svc -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317 -jar workspace.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -javaagent:/otel-auto-instrumentation/javaagent.jar```

Comment: seems to be limitation from Elastic https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html#open-telemetry-metrics-limitations

Comment: @Raushan-cs You didn't enable metric exporter `OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp` so no metrics are exported. Standard advice: read the doc

Comment: Update: after enabling metric exporter, we can see  heap memory details in Elastic. But CPU metrics and System memory usage is still have no data. So looks like ... JVM metrics that OTEL creates are not directly compatible with the fields in the Elastic APM App

Comment: looks like we need to use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-contrib/blob/main/jmx-metrics/docs/target-systems/jvm.md

Comment: any example for contrib package are available?